# How to select only specific nodes from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to select only the Code & Naam node from all the OrganisatieEenheid nodes inside the xml below. How could i do that?

```
<root>
        <OrganisatieEenheid>
           <Code>XXX</Code>
           <OrganisatieEenheidType>
              <Code></Code>
              <Naam></Naam>
           </OrganisatieEenheidType>
           <Hoofd>
              <MasterKey></MasterKey>
              <AlternateKey></AlternateKey>
              <Naam></Naam>
              <Voornaam></Voornaam>
           </Hoofd>
           <Naam>Name 1</Naam>
           <OrganisatieCode></OrganisatieCode>
           <Parent>
              <Code></Code>
              <OrganisatieEenheidType/>
              <Hoofd>
                 <MasterKey/>
                 <AlternateKey/>
                 <Naam/>
                 <Voornaam/>
              </Hoofd>
              <Naam></Naam>
              <OrganisatieCode/>
              <Parent/>
              <Niveau></Niveau>
           </Parent>
           <Niveau></Niveau>
        </OrganisatieEenheid>
        <OrganisatieEenheid>
           <Code>YYY</Code>
           <OrganisatieEenheidType>
              <Code></Code>
              <Naam></Naam>
           </OrganisatieEenheidType>
           <Hoofd>
              <MasterKey></MasterKey>
              <AlternateKey></AlternateKey>
              <Naam></Naam>
              <Voornaam></Voornaam>
           </Hoofd>
           <Naam>Name 2</Naam>
           <OrganisatieCode></OrganisatieCode>
           <Parent>
              <Code></Code>
              <OrganisatieEenheidType/>
              <Hoofd>
                 <MasterKey/>
                 <AlternateKey/>
                 <Naam/>
                 <Voornaam/>
              </Hoofd>
              <Naam></Naam>
              <OrganisatieCode/>
              <Parent/>
              <Niveau></Niveau>
           </Parent>
           <Niveau></Niveau>
        </OrganisatieEenheid>
</root>
```

So i would like to receive the output:

```
<root>
        <OrganisatieEenheid>
           <Code>XXX</Code>
           <Naam>Name 1</Naam>
        </OrganisatieEenheid>
        <OrganisatieEenheid>
           <Code>YYY</Code>
           <Naam>Name 2</Naam>
        </OrganisatieEenheid>
```

I've tried it by using the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[not(self::root or ancestor-or-self::code or ancestor-or-self::naam)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this just generates an xml like

```
<root></root>
```

Can somebody show me what the correct syntax would be for my xslt file?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//OrganisatieEenheid"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrganisatieEenheid">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="OrganisatieEenheidType/Code | OrganisatieEenheidType/Naam"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Does it? It returns a result different from the one shown in your question, because the `Code` and `Name` are copied from the `OrganisatieEenheidType` sub-branch.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I guess you are right, I might have got lost in the input structure and have copied the wrong elements. Strangely the poster seems to have been able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="OrganisatieEenheid">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Code | Naam"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```